# tcp zero window and impact on other sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a network application  reading from two sockets from Port A and Port B. The sender of data to Port A is very quick (flooding data), while the one on Port B is very slow.

If the application is very slow in consuming the data, a 'TCP Zero Window' will  show up and who sends the data to Port A will be blocked.

Do you know if a 'TCP Zero Windows' is something that affects ALL remaining ports and ALL remaining sockets open at that very moment?

Do you know if also the sender of data to Port B might be blocked as well when the TCP buffer is filled?

I am using C/C++ in Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP flow control is applied on a per-connection basis. The sliding window size on port A has no effect on port B's window size at all.

When the window size reaches zero the sender uses a periodic timer to keep probing the window size to check when your end is ready again. Allowing the window size to hit zero is bad for throughput but I'm sure you're aware of this already.

Comment: thanks a lot for confirming that. Yes unfortunately I am aware of that :(